# Views Taxonomy selection and display

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I am displaying a list of taxonomy terms for registered users on a Node and the user is asked to make multiple selections depending on what appeals to them. e.g what are their Top Ten song choices for 2016

I would like them to put that same list of taxonomy terms with their 2016 choices (Selected) within a View and I would like to email them that View list in 2017 and ask them to check if its still correct and or to make amendments to their choice to reflect their choice for 2017.

I can get the Views list to display the list of taxonomy terms, but how do I get check boxes to display with ticks with past choices for 2016 in Views and then store the changes for 2017?

Perhaps I'm overlooking something and this should be very simple.

Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds more like something Webform can take of, not sure. Webform has a load of add ons (ie Webform view etc) that might be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using following approach.

1. Create a content type for example "Favorite song" and add a field of "Term reference" type into this content type where widget will be "Check boxes/radio buttons" and select the vocabulary of songs for options.
2. Give permission to users to add/edit content "Favorite song",then while adding user will select their favorite songs from the list of songs.
3. Again to view/edit favorite song list of a user you can find the correct node by author of the node.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I have followed your instructions to the letter and I think I'm missing something .... my Views list displays as per your direction and the correct Taxonomies appear in the view, however that Checkbox on every taxonomy record is not appearing next to the taxonomy, Do you have any other suggestions. Thanks for your support, its really appreciated.

Comment: @steve, can you please explain what have you done, to do?

Comment: I have the following: Content type with taxonomy, User profile2 with taxonomy and I wish to create a view to assist in making changes / managing the profile 2 taxonomy via checkboxes in views. The Content type with taxonomy will be used to publish nodes that match the profile  2 taxonomy with the objective to send an email to the user with the profile.

Comment: @steve, give me the url, if you are comfirtable, I'll be glad to help you. my email is soaratul@gmail.com